# Jsoup select div having multiple classes

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to select, using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax), a `<div>` that has multiple classes:

```
<div class="content-text right-align bold-font">...</div>
```

The syntax for doing so, to the best of my understanding, should be:

```
document.select("div.content-text.right-align.bold-font");
```

However, for some reason, this doesn't work for me.

When I try the same exact syntax on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net), it works without a hitch.

Does multi-class selection work in **Jsoup**?

(I'd rather find out that this is a bug in my code than find out that this is a Jsoup limitation :)

**UPDATE** (thanks to the answer below): Jsoup works perfectly with the aforementioned syntax.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Works for me with latest Jsoup (1.5.2).

```
String html = "<div class=\"content-text right-align bold-font\">foo</div>";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = document.select("div.content-text.right-align.bold-font");
System.out.println(elements.text()); // foo
```

So either you're possibly using an outdated version of Jsoup which exposes a bug related to this, or the actual HTML doesn't contain a `<div>` like that.

Comment: Thanks + 1 for confirming that this indeed works. I have been using the latest Jsoup (1.5.2) but this still doesn't work for me. Could this be because my `<div>` has an id in addition to class? You are correct in assuming that the actual HTML I am trying to parse is slightly different, but AFAICT, the difference doesn't explain what I am experiencing. Should I post the full HTML section?

Comment: I would strip as much as possible from the HTML step by step as long as your function doesn't work. Once it works, go a step back and include it in your question, along with an elaboration where the conflicting part is.

Comment: Thanks + 1 again. It turns out that I had one of those moments of blindness and I was logging something different from what I was debugging. Ugrrrr...

Answer (score 1):

It would by helpfull for you in near future. Have fun.

[Jsoup selectors](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html), 
[jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)