# JSOUP: Extracting text between <div class = "..." > <p>text i want to extract</p> </div> tags

Tags: java, html, css, web-scraping, jsoup

I am currently doing a project on android studio that requires me to scrape some information from websites. I am trying to extract the text between the "p" tags from multiple elements that has the same format as the one shown below, where only the text between the "p" tags vary.

```
<div class="entry-content base-content">
        <p>
           "High-intensity interval training (AKA “HIIT”) has been a popular training method for years. 
           It’s effective and time-efficient. But, as time has gone on, the methods you see being labeled 
           as “HIIT” are getting farther away from the science that proved the effectiveness of these 
           types of routines. Just because the high intensity is good, doesn’t […]"
        </p>
</div>
```

I first got the document of the website, then I selected the elements.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); //where url is the url of the website I want to parse
Elements descData = doc.select("div.entry-content base-content");
```

I tried the following queries to get the text but all I got were empty strings
(i is the position of the element)

```
String desc = descData.eq(i).select("p").text();
String desc = descData.eq(i).select("p").toString();
String desc = descData.select("p").eq(i).text();
String desc = descData.eq(i).text();
```

Is there a way to get the text?

Comment: To describe element with multiple classes in CSS query (which is what `select` method expects) use dot operator to separate those classes like `element.class1.class2`. In your case `select("ntry-content.base-content")` (related: [Jsoup select div having multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6152671))

Comment: @Pshemo Thank you so much that solved the problem. I did not know the element was that of multiple classes.