# Get element from multiple div class with colon in css html

Tags: java, jsoup

There are 2 classes with the same name

```html
<div class="website text:middle"><a href="/class/name" class=" "> A</a></div>
<div class="website text:middle"><a href="/class/grade" class=" "> 1</a></div>
```

How to get A and 1? I tried using getElementById with `:eq(0)` and it gives out null

Comment: How exactly does your query look like? You haven't provided us with any sample Java code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method [`getElementById`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementById(java.lang.String)) queries for elements with a specified `id`, not `class`; I'm not sure what you were trying to query with `:eq(0)` either.

Try:

```java
// String html = ...
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
List<String> result = doc.getElementsByClass("text:middle").eachText();
// result = ["A", "1"]
```

**EDIT**

You *can* query for elements that match multiple classes! See [Jsoup select div having multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152671/jsoup-select-div-having-multiple-classes).

*However*, a colon (`:`) is a special character in css and needs to be escaped when it appears as part of a class name in a selector query. I don't think that jsoup currently supports this and simply treats everything after a colon as a [*pseudo-class*](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp).

Comment: Does this work with spaces? also the code gives the error The method eachText() is undefined for the type Elements

Comment: @CatMan Please see my edit. I don't understand what you meant by *"the code gives the error The method eachText() is undefined for the type Elements"* - [`eachText()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#eachText()) **is** defined on `Elements`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Janez's correct answer  - while jsoup's CSS selector (currently) doesn't support escaping a `:` character in the class name, there are other ways to get it to work if you want to use the `select()` method instead of `getElementsByXXX` -- e.g. if you want to combine selectors in one call:

```
Elements divs = doc.select("div[class=website text:middle]");
```

That will find `div` elements with the literal attribute `class="website text:middle"`. [Example](https://try.jsoup.org/%7EawqX61Q8KeFUnTpflFi9p2qVrps).

Or:

```
Elements divs = doc.select("div[class~=text:middle]");
```

That finds elements with the class attribute that matches the regex `/text:middle/`. [Example](https://try.jsoup.org/%7EIT6F-q7vvh_5Yj700MGTanw3ei8)

For the presented data though, I think think the `getElementsByClass()` DOM method is the way to go and the most general. I just wanted to show a couple alternatives for other cases.

Comment: @CatMan You should accept this answer instead of mine.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.querySelectorAll(".website")[0] // 0 is child index
```

you should use querySelector it is fully supported by every browser
check this for support details [support](https://caniuse.com/queryselector)

Comment: what he describes from his question seems like he is trying getElementById then eq(0) to get child by index there is no function in css called getElementById

Comment: for css use .website:nth-child(1) psuedo selector. index starts with 1 so 1 is first element with same class
and sorry for too many edits i am bad with editor